# ¨WorkflowScript: 35: unexpected token: catch @ line 35, column 5¨ from Jenkins build job

Tags: django, git, jenkins, groovy

Iḿ trying to deploy a build using the following Jenkins file but build job returned an error immediately. The jenkins file seems to be correct. The configuration is:

1. We have App&WebServer on cloud instance1 and installation is owned by user: preProd
2. We have Jenkins server on cloud instance2 and installation is owned by user: jenkins
3. User: jenkins public key is added into instance1 and login without password is working fine
4. The user/admin user in Jenkins web interface is ´testUser´ and using pipeline job with github key included
5. The plan is to deploy a Django build on cloud instance1
6. jenkinsfile:
7. ```
       #!groovy
          node {    
            try {
             stage 'Checkout'
              sshagent(credentials : ['1000']) {
              sh 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no preProd@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx uptime'
              sh 'ssh -v preProd@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx' }
              sh 'cd preprod-testP'
              sh 'pwd'
              sh 'ls'
              sh 'git init'
              sh 'git status'
   sh 'git pull https://xxxxxxxxxxxx:ghp_qwfaqwefdaf21asffasfas1e@github.com/testP/preprod-testP.git'
              sh 'git branch'  
          stage 'Build'
              sh 'virtualenv env -p python3'
              sh '. env/bin/activate'
              sh '/home/preProd/preprod-testP/env/bin/pip freeze'
              sh '/home/preProd/preprod-testP/env/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt'
          stage 'Test'
              sh '/home/preProd/preprod-testP/env/bin/python manage.py makemigrations'
              sh '/home/preProd/preprod-testP/env/bin/python manage.py migrate'
          stage 'Deploy'
              sh 'JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe nohup /home/preProd/preprod-testP/env/bin/python manage.py runserver
                  0.0.0.0:8000 &'
              sh 'echo "deployment is successfully completed."'
              sh 'sudo service gunicorn restart'
              sh 'sudo service nginx restart'              
                    }    

       catch (err) { 
                sh 'echo "Build failed :face_with_head_bandage: \n`${env.JOB_NAME}#${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` <${env.BUILD_URL}|Open in   
               Jenkins>"'
              throw err
                      }    
             }
   ```

we are getting this error immediately:

> Started by user testUser Obtained Jenkinsfile from git
> https://github.com/testP/preprod-testP.git
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
> startup failed: WorkflowScript: 35: unexpected token: catch @ line 35,
> column 5.
> catch (err) {
> ^
>
> 1 error
>
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:149)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:119)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:131)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:349)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:225)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:191)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:233)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:189)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:966)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:626)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
> at
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
> at
> groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
> at
> groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
> at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox$Scope.parse(GroovySandbox.java:163)
> at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:190)
> at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:175)
> at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:568)
> at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:518)
> at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:336)
> at
> hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:107)
> at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:449) Finished: FAILURE

Hope our setup is fine. I appreciate it if someone can provide a clue on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried to add formatting to your code in the question, but it's still a mess. Also looks like you don't close the sshagent block you open, which would explain the error

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates I used Ctrl+K to format the code and format appeared nice before saving it but it changed back when I saved it. It appeared that we edited at the same time. The ssh block was actually closed at the end of this line sh 'ssh -v preProd@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx' } but it was missed during the pasting and editing.

Comment: Could you edit the code so it's actually the code you have? Maybe then someone can help?

Comment: Yes @tim_yates. I was not sure my edit would take it or not but it was saved fine now. Thanks.

Comment: The first `sh 'git pull` line seems to be split over 2 lines? That's not valid groovy

Comment: It is formatted into two when I pasted here but I corrected it now.

Comment: Yes @tim_yates you are actually right about missing closed braces for 'ssh -v preProd@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx' . I corrected it again and removed extra braces at the bottom. Now the script moved to the next step but hit a whole lot of different errors that are related to the original error reported here. So, this thread can be marked as resolved. Thank you.